# Android notification how to achieve seekbar with progress bar + framelayout

Tags: android, kotlin

[Notification "seekbar"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek2fA.jpg)

So basically I want to create my own app with a "seekbar" in notification like [oled saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.js.oledsaver&hl=en&gl=US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Doled%20saver%20play%20store&pcampaignid=APPU_1_ICZtYc_KLY30rAGjlYH4Cw) and it is using progress bar + framelayout to achieve it. But so far I only achieve progress bar + framelayout with setonclickpendingintent only, means only can get click event. I don't know how to achieve like it (the progress bar progress will follow the position you clicked). Anyone can give me some ideas?

Comment: have designed own `Notification` layout? [doc in here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @snachmsm Custom notification layout no problem for me, I just don't know how to get framelayout/progressbar click position in notification and then set progress. For example, click middle will set progress to 50%